# Pyodbc query string quote escaping

Tags: python, string, escaping, pyodbc

I'm trying to execute a query using pyodbc with this kind of code

```
cursor.execute("SELECT x from y where Name='%s'"%namepar)
```

The parameter may have a quote and so it needs to be escaped in order to work, how do i do thos? I tried by simply replacing " ' " with " \\' " in namepar and it still doesn't work, I get a pyodbc.ProgrammingError

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass parameters, and that will be escaped.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT x from y where Name = ?", (namepar,))
```

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15

http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor

Answer (score -4):

You could also try putting an extra set of quotes around it. It worked in my use case.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT x from y where Name=''%s''" % namepar)
```

Comment: This is vunlerable to the SQL injection attack.