# Python pyodbc Sql

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am not sure if I am approaching this in the best way.  I need to use the results of an array to generate dynamic sql.

I am trying to run a sql statement with a variable that comes from an array

```
 while count <=len(ArrayList) -1:
     ID = ArrayList[count,0] 
     AnotherValue = ArrayList[count,1]

     sql = """ select Column1, Column2 from Atable where ID = """ + ID  + """ and AnotherValue = """ + AnotherValue

     sqlResults= pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

     count +=1
```

How can I use a variable to run the statement in a loop?  Or other suggestions?  Thank you!

I am getting this error:

```
 TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U254') dtype('<U254') dtype('<U254')
```

I also tried this:

```
     while count <=len(ArrayList) -1:
         ID = ArrayList[count,0] 
          AnotherValue = ArrayList[count,1]

     sql = """ select Column1, Column2 from Atable where ID = $ID and AnotherValue = $AnotherValue """

     sqlResults= pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

     count +=1
```

and it got this error

```
 ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid pseudocolumn "$ID". (126) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: You can't run an sql statement without creating a connection and a cursor just before your loop, to execute your sql statement inside the loop. Is this your question?

Comment: please edit your question and post the errors thrown, also we can't debug code we don't see...

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully it helps.  thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: see a parametric query example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139487/pyodbc-query-string-quote-escaping. You shouldn't concatenate strings like that because of sql injection attacks. Also it looks to me the variables you are concatenating are not a strings, and/or the plus signal is passing to database driver as a sum, instead of the concatenation you wanted.